# Entity framework creates new entity with relation to existing entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have `Student` entity which has `Class` (Class can have many students)

This is my Student.cs and StudentDto.cs

```
 public partial class Students
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int? FkClass { get; set; }
}

public class StudentsDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int FkClass { get; set; }
    public int FkClassNavigationId { get; set; }
    public string FkClassNavigationTitle { get; set; }
}
```

When I am creating new student and select class id from the dropdown, instead of using that class, new class is created (with null values and random ID).
I am not sure where is the best way to fix this mistake? Is it the problem in Automapper, context.cs class or my add method is wrong itself?

In my service I do this:

```
public Students PostStudent(StudentsDTO item)
    {
        var sub = _mapper.Map<Students>(item);
        _repository.PostStudent(sub);
        return sub;
    }
```

and In the repository I do the following:

```
 public void PostStudent(Students c)
    {
        this.museumContext.Add(c);
        this.museumContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Automapper.cs:

```
            CreateMap<Students, StudentsDTO>()
            .ReverseMap();
```

and context.s

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Students>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("students");
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            entity.Property(e => e.FkClass).HasColumnName("fkClass");

            entity.Property(e => e.FullName)
                .HasColumnName("fullName")
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.FkClassNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FkClass)
                .HasConstraintName("Include");
        });
```

Can someone help me understand how to fix this?

The weird thing is if I add `var a = _classesService.GetClassById(s.FkClass);` to my controller it works fine. It's  not that I'm assigning what I retrieve or anything.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult PostStudent([FromBody] StudentsDTO s)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            var a = _classesService.GetClassById(s.FkClass);
            var sub = this._service.PostStudent(s);
            return Ok();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return BadRequest(err);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your mapping correct? It looks suspicious for me. Is there a class named "Class"? Are you missing a property of that type in the entity Student? I have faced some wrong behaviors like the one you reported. The problems were always in the mapping. One classical mistake i made many times were in the bidirectional associations.